# DevOps for vue application distributed to multiple clients on multiple subdomains

Tags: docker, vue.js, vuejs3, devops

I am creating a Saas product and have a VueJS frontend that I want to distribute to multiple clients on multiple subdomains.

Currently I point all subdomains to the same static files. Once the Vue app starts, I send a request to a Laravel application with the current subdomain as the parameter.  This returns client variables such as the app name and the api endpoint.  This was my round about way of having env values at runtime.

I am pretty new to DevOps and not sure which direction to go. If I signup multiple clients I am worried that having one single set of static files they all use it would lead to performance issues.

I am not sure what kind of CICD solution I should use with a Vue Application.

Is there some sort of containerized solution I should use to handle this instead of just having static files on an apache server?

Comment: I'd expect serving static files to be pretty inexpensive, and if you have a multi-tenant SaaS application I'd expect every tenant to get the same static files.  What specific problem are you running into?

Comment: Yes I agree for serving static files it should be inexpensive and I could possibly use a CDN if needed. The issue is having different environment variables for each "application tenant".  They each have their own API endpoint to run their application.  I was trying to see if it is possible to create a build process to have separate env files for each tenant.

Comment: Usually, you would parameterize things at deployment time - and not at build time. Your application however should support parametrization.